# how a user comments form can be submitted and displayed on same page in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on a project where user can upload comments and i want to display all the uploaded data on that same page where user uploaded the data how can i achieve that please help me with this what is the good way to do that.i have tried following thing but i could not getting the expected result

```
            public ActionResult Gandhiji(int? id)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "150 Years Of Gandhiji";

                IEnumerable<UserComments> obj = db.UserComments;
                if(id!=null)
                {
                    obj = obj.Where(p => p.Id == id);
                }

                return View("Gandhiji",obj);
            }




                @model BigFoot.UsercommentsImage
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Gandhiji", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <h4 style="margin-left:30px;">User Comments</h4>
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "Phone Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Picture:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input class="form-control" type="file" id="UploadedFile" name="UploadedFile" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }



    <img src="@Item.Path"/>

            </div>

        </div>



   public class UsercommentsImage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Phone]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return json and bind it any control like input, label or span. You need to change return view to return json.

JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#InputDate").live('click', function () {
        var date = $("#InputDate").val();
        if (date != "") {
            $.getJSON("/Home/GetNames",
                    { date: $("#InputDate").val() },
                    function (data) {
                        $("#ProviderName").empty();
                        // [...]
                        });
                    });
        }
    });
});
```

And C#

```
public JsonResult GetNames(string date)
 {
   List<Provider> list = new List<Provider>();
   // [...]
   return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```